# Ember calling common code across objects

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to Ember and have a question regarding where to put common code.
Consider a simple scenario. I have an AJAX request and I want to use the response in multiple places (say a route and in some controller OR 2 different controllers)

I have 2 questions;

1. In Ember, can I access any controller (say X.js) from any other
   controller (say Y.js), by just using
   this.controllerFor(this.routeName)
2. If the above is true, is that a better approach for common code (i.e. having a property in X controller to save the common API response) and then using it in another controller Y OR Should I use Ember Service for the common code and through dependency injection, consume the common code/API response ?

What is the correct way for this use case ?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use Ember Service for the common code and through dependency
>   injection, consume the common code/API response?

Yes you should use Ember Service for that.

Reasons:

- Controllers will be removed and replaced by components in future
- You can inject service in any controller, route or even component
- Better code abstraction and separation of concerns